# Understanding how Mule ESB fits in with JDBC and REST

Tags: java, rest, jdbc, mule, esb

I have this simple REST service running in our JBoss app server which works great.  For now, the service has one @GET method (getAllPeople), which makes a JDBC connection to a mysql database, to retrieve some data (SELECT name, address FROM Person).

My team lead wants me to experiment with Mule ESB, and use this simple project as a starting point.  I'm confused on how to make this work with a Mule flow. I set up my flow with an HTTP inbound point, REST component, and JDBC component, like this:

[image]

I configured the JDBC component to use MySQL, and added a query to it (SELECT name, address FROM Person).

The question: The code in my REST service @GET method is still connecting directly to the DB with JDBC. I think I need to change this to instead, invoke the Mule JDBC datasource instead, but I have no idea how to do this.  What code do I need to put in my REST service @GET method to utilize the Mule JDBC component, and get a result? I am trying to get a grasp on how the components talk to each other.

EDIT: new thought - Should an ESB be used to link different components of a single system together, such as REST services, SOAP services, and JDBC data sources, or should an ESB be used only to connect completely independent systems together?

Comment: ESBs in general are quite good to integrate disparate systems where there's a considerable amount of chatter between the applications. For what you're saying, you application is quite simple... so please keep it like that and **run** away from ESBs, they will make your environment more complex and will introduce new failure scenarios. In my view, ESBs is the last resort for complex integrations. Answering your question this mule [example](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation-3.2/display/32X/Hello+World+Example) is similar to what you want to do.

Comment: I understand what your saying, and agree with you. However, this is just a practice project for learning/understanding how Mule works. I do realize that an ESB is complete overkill for a small project like this, but I still need to learn how they work for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

To make your trivial example work, just delete the REST component and add an Object to JSON transformer after the JDBC component. Your flow will then return the query results in JSON format.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like that would work in this case, but eventually, i will need to work with more complex REST services, and would like to know how REST and JDBC interaction works. Eventually, I will need to do more complex data processing in my service, and store/retrieve data based on processing results. Now this has me wondering: if my REST service is completely dependent on my database, and the service and the database are part of a unified system, then maybe an ESB should not be used in this way.

Comment: Typically, you would use the JDBC component when you are not using a REST component backed by a Java service class. It's just a simple facade to use if you need db i/o somewhere inside your Mule app. If you are to "experiment with Mule", I suggest you try to implement your processing needs with the different Mule components instead of plugging in Java classes.

Comment: I see. Thanks, you have been helpful. I was trying to think of Mule ESB as just a collection of resources that can utilize one another, but I think I really need to think more in terms of workflows.

Answer (score 0):

We can use mule here to call the rest api, rest api will return some data that may not be sufficient. In order to get more data from db based on the result of rest call (transformed by JsontoObject) jdbc connector could be used. In your case if you want to call rest api which eventually calls the DB, you will get json or xml which can be transformed to send the data to outbounds.

Thanks-

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you have that 'rest' component in between. that may not be needed. the simplest would be to have the http, and a transformer (to transform the data from http to/from), and a jdbc component. with this approach you are leaving behind the existing ReST service in JBoss App Server.

I think in the posted picture you try to call the pre-existing ReST service in Jboss App Server which may not be needed. You can simply immitate what the existing service does. or you may consider the existing service and the new mule service can act as a proxy service - in such a case the JDBC component is not required.